# My findViewById is not working. in my fragment

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments

My findViewById is not working. it does not link...

////my fragment.contacts.xml

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtShowOnMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/locationonmap"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:labelFor="@id/btnShowOnMap"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="@string/store_location" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShowOnMap"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/map" />

    </LinearLayout>*
```

////end of fragmentcontacts.xml

my contactsfragment.kt

[image: contactsfragments.kt]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Make it **view.findViewById**
For fragment you need to add rootview.